# Magento Customers edit is broken in the backend admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, backend

After I updated few security patches in my local Magento 1.9.3.8.
PHP 7.o-fpm, nginx server.

```
SUPEE-10888
SUPEEE-10975
SUPEE-11085
SUPEE-11155
```

So when I was testing all functionalities I saw that when I click on edit customer on the backend something was wrong because I could only see this:

[image]

I then go and check the logs back there was nothing in logs I also checked the nginx `error.log` I realised that everytime I click edit the logs are being populated as follow.

```
2019/07/08 08:26:21 [error] 6266#6266: *169 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class Mage_Customer_Helper_Address, because the name is already in use in /home/ntabethemba/projects/nlg/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Address.php on line 0
PHP message: PHP Stack trace:
PHP message: PHP   1. {main}() /home/ntabethemba/projects/nlg/index.php:0
PHP message: PHP   2. Mage::run() /home/ntabethemba/projects/nlg/index.php:85
PHP message: PHP   3. Mage_Core_Model_App->run() /home/ntabethemba/projects/nlg/app/Mage.php:683
PHP message: PHP   4. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() /home/ntabethemba/projects/nlg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:365
PHP message: PHP   5. Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Admin->match() /home/ntabethemba/projects/nlg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:172
PHP message: PHP   6. Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController->dispatch() /home/ntabethemba/projects/nlg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php:254
PHP message: PHP   7. Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController->editAction() /home/ntabethemba/projects/nlg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:418
PHP message: PHP   8. Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController->renderLayout() /home/ntabethemba/projects/nlg/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php:161
PHP message: PHP   9. Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput() /home/ntabethemba/projects/nlg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:390
PHP message: PHP  10. Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page->toHtml() /home/ntabethemba/projects/nlg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:555
PHP message: PHP  11. Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page->_toHtml() /home/ntabethemba/projects/nlg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php:923
PHP message: PHP  12. Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page->_toHtml() /home/ntabethemba/projects/nlg/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php:81
PHP message: PHP  13. Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page->renderView() /home/ntabethemba/projects/nlg/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php:286
```

I looked for the duplication of this class `Mage_Customer_Helper_Address` I couldn't find it. so I follow another pages that are in the logs when I check the code seems to be okay. I also edited this file during patching manually customerController.php

```
/**
     * Customer edit action
     */
    public function editAction()
    {
        $this->_initCustomer();
        $this->loadLayout();

        /* @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer */
        $customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');

        // set entered data if was error when we do save
        $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getCustomerData(true);

        // restore data from SESSION
        if ($data) {
            $request = clone $this->getRequest();
            $request->setParams($data);

            if (isset($data['account'])) {
                /* @var $customerForm Mage_Customer_Model_Form */
                $customerForm = Mage::getModel('customer/form');
                $customerForm->setEntity($customer)
                    ->setFormCode('adminhtml_customer')
                    ->setIsAjaxRequest(true);
                $formData = $customerForm->extractData($request, 'account');
                $customerForm->restoreData($formData);
            }

            if (isset($data['address']) && is_array($data['address'])) {
                /* @var $addressForm Mage_Customer_Model_Form */
                $addressForm = Mage::getModel('customer/form');
                $addressForm->setFormCode('adminhtml_customer_address');

                foreach (array_keys($data['address']) as $addressId) {
                    if ($addressId == '_template_') {
                        continue;
                    }

                    $address = $customer->getAddressItemById($addressId);
                    if (!$address) {
                        $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
                        $customer->addAddress($address);
                    }

                    $formData = $addressForm->setEntity($address)
                        ->extractData($request);
                    $addressForm->restoreData($formData);
                }
            }
        }

        $this->_title($customer->getId() ? $customer->getName() : $this->__('New Customer'));

        /**
         * Set active menu item
         */
        $this->_setActiveMenu('customer/new');

        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

I am running out of options I'd appreciate if anyone can help.

Thank you.